# Appending button to element not accessible by variable

Tags: jquery

I have some code where I am trying to access a button that is appended to an element by a variable. As you can see the button is not being removed from the page. Why is this?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LtARQ/)

```
var myButton = $('.mybutton');
$('#parentDiv').append('<button class="mybutton">Button</button>');
myButton.remove();
```

Comment: The button doesn't exist when you make the selection. your call to `myButton.remove()` affects no elements.

Comment: On the first line no .mybutton exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get the '.mybutton' element before creating it, so it doesn't exist.

```
$('#parentDiv').append('<button class="mybutton">Button</button>');
var mybutton = $('.mybutton');
mybutton.remove();
```